# How to remove scripts/style added to customize_controls_enqueue_scripts hook by current active theme

Tags: hooks, wp-enqueue-script, theme-customizer, wp-enqueue-style

I am looking for a way to remove/unhook all assets (css and javascript) files added to customize_controls_enqueue_scripts hook when the query string `mo-reset=true` is added to the customize url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `global $wp_scripts` and `global $wp_styles;` to get all registerd scripts and styles.

Eg.

[image]

All **Scripts**

```
// All Scripts
global $wp_scripts;

$all_scripts = array();

foreach( $wp_scripts->registered as $script ) :
    $all_scripts[$script->handle] = $script->src;
endforeach;

// echo '<pre>';
// print_r( $all_scripts );
// echo '</pre>';
```

All **Styles**

```
// All Styles
global $wp_styles;

$all_styles = array();

foreach( $wp_styles->registered as $style ) :
    $all_styles[$style->handle] = $style->src;
endforeach;

// echo '<pre>';
// print_r( $all_styles );
// echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Awesome. Exactly what I needed. Thanks @maheshwaghmare

Answer (score 0):

Check [wp_deregister_script](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_deregister_script)().

Comment: That requires I know the handles. Which I don't know. I need to programatically know all handles added by the current theme.

Comment: I don't know if you can do get those handles by code.